# In for loops, does the length of the array get evaluated each iteration?

Tags: java

if I have a for loop like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { ... }
```

...does `myArray.length`get evaluated every iteration? So would something like...

```
int len = myArray.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { ... }
```

... be a small performance increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form will probably incur some performance penalty, since evaluating it will require, before the `iflt`, an `aload`, an `arraylength` and an `iload`; whereas the second is only two `iload`s.

@ajp rightly mentions that `myArray` may *change*; so it is highly *unlikely* that the *compiler* will optimize the first form into the second for you (unless, maybe, `myArray` is `final`).

However, the JIT, when it kicks in, is probably smart enough so that, if `myArray` doesn't change, it will turn the first form into the second.

Just in case, anyway, use the second form (this is what I always do, but that's just out of habit). Note that you can always `javap` the generated class file to see the generated byte code and compare.

---

By the way, Wikipedia has a [very handy page listing all of a JVM's bytecodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings). As you may see, quite a lot of them are dedicated to arrays!

Comment: `arraylength` is the instruction to load the length of the array, `iload` is the one to load the value of a local variable. There is an instruction (albeit named differently) to be evaluated either way. As for the fact that array may change, well ... so can a local variable.

Comment: And? That doesn't justify the donwvote at all. Read the comment to your prior remark and the edited answer.

Comment: I did not downvote you. Although, I do think it would be justified actually :) I think this answer is misleading.

Comment: @Dima sure, but even if it changes it will still be only a single `iload` against an `aload` + `arraylength` :p

Comment: I am just saying, that the fact that the array can change is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Dima eh? I believe it is PLENTY relevant, on the contrary. As I said in the answer too, if the array does NOT change then the compiler may very well decide, if it detects it, to generate different bytecode. As to "misleading", I fail to see why.

Answer (score 5):

regardless  `myArray.length` is just a field so there is nothing to evaluate

Java array has length as `public final int` so it gets initialized once and when you refer to it there is no code execution like a method call

> The public final field length, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be [positive or zero.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7)

Comment: Uhm, not quite true. There is a bytecode instruction to get the length of an array (`arraylength`). So yes, there is "something to evaluate"...

Comment: It might be worth pointing out, however, that the expression is evaluated, meaning that, had length been a method/function, it would indeed be called for each iteration.

Comment: yes but not when you refer to it, only when you initialize it

Comment: Err... The middle of a for loop is a _condition_. Unless the compiler treats the case or array lengths specifically, the `arraylength` opcode and the `iflt` accompanying it _will_ be evaluated each time! And that is more expensive than a single `iflt`.

Comment: @fge so doing `int len = myArray.length` would increase performance?

Comment: @ÞórÓðinsson as I say in my answer, maybe, maybe not; you really need to `javap` the generated class file and see for yourself. And then there's the JIT to account for.

Comment: @fge how is it different then  referring to local variable then referring to a field variable from array class ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi because when you use a local variable the `arraylength` opcode is only evaluated _once_

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.arraylength isn't it O(1) ? and evelution of this opcode (if JIT doesn't cache it) would be expensive ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi event if it is, the fact is, it is an opcode on each condition which you can easily avoid; just do so

Comment: @fge `iload` is also a bytecode. `if(len < n)` does  `iload #len;`, `if(array.length < n)` does `arraylength #array`. Same difference.

Comment: @Dima of course not. Read what you say again. You need to `aload` the array, then to `arraylength` on it, then `iload` n. If the length is in a variable already, this is just two `iload`s.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the termination expression gets evaluated every time.  So you're right that storing the length once could be a small performance increase.  But more importantly, it changes the logic, which could make a difference if `myArray` gets reassigned.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (something-something-something) {
        myArray = appendToMyArray(myArray, value);  // sets myArray to a new, larger array
    }
}
```

Now it makes a big difference whether you store the array length in a variable first.

You wouldn't normally see code like this with an array.  But with an `arrayList` or other collection, whose size could increase (or decrease) in the body of the loop, it makes a **big** difference whether you compute the size once or every time.  This idiom shows up in algorithms where you keep a "To-Do list".  For example, here's a partial algorithm to find everyone who's connected directly or indirectly to some person:

```
ArrayList<Person> listToCheck = new ArrayList<>(KevinBacon);
for (int i = 0; i < listToCheck.size(); i++) {
    List<Person> connections = allConnections(listToCheck.get(i));
    for (Person p : connections) {
        if ([p has not already been checked]) {
            listToCheck.add(p);  // increases listToCheck.size()!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good spotting about "the array may change" but my word, if you see such code you should run away :p

Comment: if u remove elements from arraylist, arraylist does not decrease its size as far as I know

Comment: @KickButtowski uh, it it doesn't, it violates the `.size()` method contract!

Comment: @KickButtowski Yes, it does, since `size()` returns the number of elements actually in the array.  The _capacity_ may stay the same, but that's not what `size()` returns.  (I don't think `ArrayList` has a method that returns the current capacity.)

Comment: Re "the array (reference) may change": I don't see there's any mystery. Either it does change or it doesn't, and the JIT compiler knows whether or not it ever changes. If it doesn't, it can potentially optimise out the length field read on every iteration.

Comment: @fge :-)  I've been working as a compiler maintainer for some time.  The compiler has to handle code correctly no matter how smelly it is.  I don't **get** to run away from it.

Comment: @NeilCoffey the JIT, yes; the compiler, I gather, doesn't take any such chance (since, hey, the JIT will take care of that anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Both cases are comparing the value at two memory addresses with every iteration, except you are doing unnecessary assigning when you use a `len` variable. The performance difference is probably very small, and the first line is more readable, so I would use the first way as it is more readable. If you want to be even more readable and efficient, use a for-each loop if you are just going to do a linear iteration through your array. For-each loops look work like this:

```
int [] myArray = {1,2,3};
for(int i:myArray){
System.out.print(i);
}
```

will print:

```
1
2
3
```

as i is set to each element of the array. The for each loop can be used for many objects, and is a nice feature to learn.
Here is a guide explaining it.

https://www.udemy.com/blog/for-each-loop-java/